# Is there a way that I can set buildConfigField value from build.gradle to view directly in layout xml file?

Tags: android, xml, build.gradle

Let's say I set some `buildConfigField` for my specific flavor in my build.gradle file, for example:

```
...
productFlavors{
    stage {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST_URL', '"https://someurl.com"'
    ....
    }
```

}

I would like to set, not programmatically, text in TextView in my layout xml that belongs to this flavor to this value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
resValue "string", "whatever", '"your string literal goes here"'
```

in each of your flavors. Then, refer to `R.string.whatever` in your layout.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare! Is there a way by any chance to do similar with `versionName` to be referenced without programming on layout xml? (usage: put it in the layout of splash screen)

Comment: @DevetiPutnik: Set up another `resValue`, where you use the same value as you use for `versionName`. There might be a way to iterate over all variants and do this, rather than having individual per-flavor `resValue` statements, though I have not tried this.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that is the only solution.